# Retrieving data to appear for drag and drop

Tags: php, html

As you can see div1 will be the first box. The sentence "我 的 名 字 叫 小 明 。" should be appear inside the first box. This sentence "我 的 名 字 叫 小 明 。" is from the database, which have been retrieve out from the database. I want this sentence "我 的 名 字 叫 小 明 。" to appear inside of the first box instead of this(http://pho.to/66hLl ). Please click the link in order to see where the sentence is appearing now. I want the sentence "我 的 名 字 叫 小 明 。" to be appearing in the top box instead so that i will be able to drag the individual character into the second box! Thank you!:)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Hello world</title>
    <style>
        div {width:300px; height:200px; border:1px solid; margin:50px; border-radius:10px;          
        background-color:rgba(255,0,0,0.1); color:black; padding:20px;}
        #drag1{cursor:move}
    </style>
    <script>
        function allowDrop(ev) {
            ev.preventDefault();
        }
        function drag(ev) {
            ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text",ev.target.id);
        }
        function drop(ev) {
            ev.preventDefault();
            var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
            ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
        }
    </script>

</head>
<body>
<center>

<h1>create a proper sentence by dragging to the exact place.</h1>


<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
<section id="drag1">

<a class= "<?php  echo "<dt>Sentence:</dt><dd>" . $row[$order[0]] . " " .     

$row[$order[1]] . " " .
$row[$order[2]] . " " . $row[$order[3]] ."</dd>";  ?>"</a>width="100"height="100"  
draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)"/></div>



<div id="div2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>


<?php
    // Connect to database server
    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "password") or die (mysql_error ());

    // Select database
    mysql_select_db("login") or die(mysql_error());

    // set utf8 unicode mode to set chinese character 

    mysql_query ( 'SET NAMES utf8' ); 

    $strSQL = "SELECT * FROM chinesesen WHERE id=1 ;";


    //create an array with numbers 1-4
    $order = array(1,2,3,4);

    //shuffle them in random order
    $rs = mysql_query($strSQL);

    // Loop the recordset $rs
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {
    // Write the data of the person
    //Display all the array values from 0-3 (array index starts from 0)
    echo "<dt>Sentence:</dt><dd>" . $row[$order[0]] . " " . $row[$order[1]] . " " .
    $row[$order[2]] . " " . $row[$order[3]] ."</dd>";

    }
    // Close the database connection
    mysql_close();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have your `PHP` declarations instantiated before you try to access them

```
 <?php
// Connect to database server
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "password") or die (mysql_error ());

// Select database
mysql_select_db("login") or die(mysql_error());

// set utf8 unicode mode to set chinese character 

mysql_query ( 'SET NAMES utf8' ); 

$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM chinesesen WHERE id=1 ;";


//create an array with numbers 1-4
 $order = array(1,2,3,4);

//shuffle them in random order
 $rs = mysql_query($strSQL);


 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {

    $sentence =  "<dt>Sentence:</dt><dd>" . $row[$order[0]] . " " . $row[$order[1]] . " " .
   $row[$order[2]] . " " . $row[$order[3]] ."</dd>";

}

 mysql_close();
 ?>


  <div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
  <section id="drag1">

  <a class= "<?php  echo "<dt>Sentence:</dt><dd>" . $row[$order[0]] . " " .     

   $row[$order[1]] . " " .
   $row[$order[2]] . " " . $row[$order[3]] ."</dd>";  ?>
   <?php echo $sentence;?>
   </a>
   <div width="100" height="100"  
   draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)"/></div>



<div id="div2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
```

**EDIT**

If you want to do what I think you want to do...then this might be the way...

```
  <?php foreach($row as $r){;?>

    <div width="100" height="100" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)"/>
       <?php echo $r;?>
    </div>

   <? };?>
```

Comment: @Darren I tried php declaration first, like the code you give but the sentence "我 的 名 字 叫 小 明 。" still do not appear in the first box. It display above the box, outside of the box. I ant it to be inside the first box.  Please click the link in order to see where the sentence is appearing now. http://postimg.org/image/d46hrftp5/

Comment: Edited.....assigned the results to a $sentence variable, then echo the $sentence within the div.  However, this is still likely not what you want, as you seem to want the letters to all be seperate?

Comment: If i dont want to use echo and want to use a label or a string and get which elements from the database. (Please see the database in order to understand what i mean - http://postimg.org/image/xb9qklr95/) . For example, $strSQL = "SELECT * FROM chinesesen WHERE id=1 ;"; and to display what is in "one", "two", "three" and "four" when id = 1.

Comment: Well each seperate string would just be in the $row variable.  So $row[0], $row[1], $row[2], or if you have column names.  $row['column1'], $row['column2'] etc etc  Or just do a foreach loop and echo them out

Comment: Check my edit...I think that might be what you want  Although I dunno what the <dd> and <dt> are doing in your original, they might be related to the dragging and dropping, so you mght have to wrap each echo in one of them

Comment: I dont really get what you mean. what should i add in the edits?

Comment: If i want use label i dont want to use echo at all how can i do it?